# How to implement a request in MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

There is an IoT server that only supports MQTT protocol and the administrator shared below code in order to get data from the server

```
mosquitto_sub -v -t "app/26" -h broker.example.com -p 1883  -u "dir1-mqtt" -P "5sp-1001-tech
```

Actually i don't know how to deal with it.

How can i send that request to the target and get the response in a fastest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is, you don't. Your model of MQTT is wrong.

MQTT is not a request/response model<sup>*</sup> e.g. like HTTP, it is a publish/subscribe (pub/sub) messaging model. In a pub/sub model a data producer publishes a message to a topic, there could be anywhere from 0 to N subscribers to that topic, the publisher has no way of knowing how many subscribers there are (and really shouldn't care).

This means all you need to do to receive the data is to subscribe to the topic provided (in this case `app/26`) and when there is new data it will be delivered to your client.

There are options to make sure that when you subscribe you always get the last published message. This is done by the producing client setting the retained bit in the message header, which will cause the broker to hold on to this message and deliver it first to all clients when they subscribe to a topic. The next message with this bit set on that topic will replace the previous. But this is in the control of the client producing the data, not the consumer.

<sup>*</sup> You can implement request/response using separate topics and MQTT v5 has an extra header to specify the response topic. But requires the client producing the data to be expecting to receive request on a given topic and being capable of replying on the supplied topic.

Comment: depend on your answer, i am consumer and should subscribe to the new published message. how to subscribe for the published message and am i have to be always online to be informed of new message?

Comment: as a matter of fact the server only keeps data for 30 mins and data will be removed or back ups on other server so i am have to get data before lost.

Comment: Under normal circumstances you have to be connected to the broker all the time to receive messages, if the messages only contain the last 30mins of history then that is all you will get. It is possible to set up a persistent subscription so the broker will queue messages for an offline client and deliver them when you reconnect. But that is a very different question.